# Any Opensource PHP Agile/Scrum Options?

Tags: php, open-source, agile, scrum

I am looking around at some open-source agile management tools, one in which can handle, around 10-15 people, is open source, and preferably built in PHP.

Has anyone come across anything remotely like this?

Comment: http://pm-sherpa.com/attributes/opensource/

Comment: @Sukumar: Please post your answer as an answer so we can upvote it properly.

Comment: Wow! I really don't know what to do here. Last time I posted an answer that was just a link, I was told to post it in the comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see http://pm-sherpa.com/ for a comprehensive list for project management softwares and specifically http://pm-sherpa.com/attributes/opensource/ for open source ones.

Comment: This is helpful, I am open now to looking for cloud/hosted services too. The first link does a great job compiling the list.

Comment: The list in the second link doesn't include any scrum/agile tool. By the way, that website made my eyes bleed.

Answer (score 2):

You will find a list of open source scrum tools on http://www.opensourcescrum.com/